# Empty MainActivity , Navigation not working?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I have read Documentation, Followed CodeLab, and watched youtube tutorials but whenever I try **navigation** on my own some or the other problem occurs,
This time **my HomeFragment is not being hosted in the NavHost and I see a blank screen on launching the app.**
I believe I have a Proper `NavGraph`, `NavHost` but I am not navigating yet so no `NavController`. 
Here are my files and classes:-

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/appInfoFragment"
        android:name="com.example.themaze.AppInfoFragment"
        android:label="fragment_app_info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_app_info" />
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.themaze.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_appInfoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/appInfoFragment" />
   </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:background="@color/teal_200">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

It would be a **great help if I get an answer** as I have spent more than an hour figuring out the problem on the topic I thought I knew...

Comment: I am sure I have set proper dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your activity_main.xml. Instead of using a fragment, please use a FragmentContainerView to host your fragment. Like this,

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

For more detail, check out https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost